# groupby returns multilevel dataframe when used in a column with text

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to group some signals and concatenate the text at the same time for that I use something similar to the code below. Where I use the sum_x custom function to concatenate the text under 'text'

```
lst = [{'name': 'A', 'reg': '1', 'text': 'txt1', 'value': 5},
{'name': 'A', 'reg': '1', 'text': 'txt2', 'value': 2},
{'name': 'B', 'reg': '2', 'text': 'txt3', 'value': 2}]
data = pd.DataFrame(lst) 
sum_x = lambda x : x.sum()
data.groupby(by=['name', 'reg']).apply(sum_x)

Out[48]: 
        name reg      text  value
name reg                          
A    1     AA  11  txt1txt2      7
B    2      B   2      txt3      2
```

This however do not produce the expected result
Notice how the text column was added as expected but also the 'by' columns where concatenated. The response also have an extra level.
is it posible to obtain something like:

```
name reg      text  value       
 A   1     txt1txt2      7
 B   2         txt3      2
```

where the columns in 'by' are preserved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
In [21]: data.groupby(['name', 'reg']).agg({'value':'sum', 'text':'sum'}).reset_index()
Out[21]:
  name reg      text  value
0    A   1  txt1txt2      7
1    B   2      txt3      2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can select the columns the `groupby` operation works on:

```
 In [21]: data.groupby(by=['name', 'reg'])[['text', 'value']].apply(sum_x)
Out[21]:
              text  value
name reg
A    1    txt1txt2      7
B    2        txt3      2
```

Finally, if you do not want the `name` and `reg` in the index, you can use `reset_index()`:

```
In [22]: data.groupby(by=['name', 'reg'])[['text', 'value']].apply(sum_x).reset_index()
Out[22]:
  name reg      text  value
0    A   1  txt1txt2      7
1    B   2      txt3      2
```